# Why using focusout with jQuery works for Firefox while using addEventListener doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, focusout

I read in MDN that `focusout` doesn't work on Firefox but why using it with jQuery works. What is the sorcery behind jQuery?
Thanks.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mf00h6j/)

```js
$(".input1").on("focusout", function() {
    console.log("jquery focusout");
});

document.querySelector(".input2").addEventListener("focusout",  function(){
 console.log("focusout");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="input1" type="text" />
<input class="input2" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery gets around this issue by using the standard `focus` and `blur` events and setting the capture phase argument for `addEventListener`.

[Here is the relevant source file.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c9935b6d2db9e1be4bed12f7419e98cdca45763e/src/event/focusin.js)

In you example, you can replace:

```
document.querySelector(".input2").addEventListener("focusout",  function(){
    console.log("focusout");
});
```

With:

```
document.querySelector(".input2").addEventListener("blur",  function(){
    console.log("focusout");
}, true);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkxjb9b2/)

```js
$(".input1").on("focusout", function() {
    console.log("jquery focusout");
});

document.querySelector(".input2").addEventListener("blur",  function(){
    console.log("focusout");
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="input1" type="text" />
<input class="input2" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is [not supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout#Browser_compatibility) and [jQuery has workaround for that](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c9935b6d2db9e1be4bed12f7419e98cdca45763e/src/event/focusin.js) (basically, translating it to `blur` event listener).